# Same hover effect for all link children in CSS

Tags: css

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="">Bioshock 2<span> - Xbox 360 review</span></a>
```

I'd like to style the first part of the link in one way and the `span` in another, like this:

[image: Example]

I've managed to do this, using the following CSS:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a span {
    color: #c8c8c8;
}

a:link, 
a:visited {
    color: #787878;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #a10000;
}
```

However, it doesn't work as expected when I hover over it:

[image: Example]

I'd like the entire link to have the same hover effect and not have the `span` keep its colour. I'd also like this to happen whether you're hovering over the `span` or the rest of the link. The desired effect would look like this:

[image: Example]

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
a:hover, a:active, a:hover span {
  // ...
}
```

instead of:

```
a:hover, a:active {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css code to it:

```
a span:hover {
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #a10000;
}
```

**[And here is the demonstration. :)](http://jsbin.com/isuxa3)**

Comment: The effect for the `span` only works when you're hovering over the `span` though, not if you're hovering over the rest of the link.

Comment: `a span:hover` is less widely supported than `a:hover span`.